# How do I fix problems when going from 3G to a Wi-Fi connection that requires a login?

Tags: wi-fi

Whenever I'm in the basement of my university's science building, I have no cell signal, so I am forced use the school's WiFi network to get internet.  However, for what seems like the better part of an hour after connecting to the hotspot, my phone refuses to show me the login page so I can connect to the internet at large, simply saying:

> **Data connectivity problem**  The server failed to communicate.  Try again later.

If I just go to class in the morning and let my phone connect to WiFi while still having a cell signal available if needed, I occasionally have this problem, but usually by the end of the hour it will play nice and show me the login page.

Is there something I can do to force my phone to wise up to the fact that I need to login without just waiting around?

- Restarting the phone does work, but takes a fair bit of time and seems excessive
- Clearing the cache in the browser (Menu, Settings, Clear cache) does nothing

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: what browser are you using? Compressing proxy browser (e.g. Opera Mini) cannot be used to log into login systems since they rely on their proxy to compress the HTML to a simpler format they understand.

Comment: Some university's hotspots are unencrypted but require a web-based authentication (nocat or similar). Before auth is done https traffic is blocked (or redirected with a *fake* certificate) and http is redirected to the login page. Thus Opera mini  and all SSL based traffic fails. Fix: open any unsecure http only site, get redirected to the auth page and login at first.

Comment: @nickT is your problem solved meanwhile? If so, would you mind to answer your own question and then accept your answer -- so others can see how to deal with this issue when affected? Thanks!